# Selenium Web Scraping data-msg-id inside class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the number inside data-msg-id but i'm having some problems with that.
My main problem is that when I try to get it, selenium return nothing "[]"

Here is the html i'm trying to find  the data-msg-id:

```
<div class="im_message_outer_wrap hasselect" ng-click="toggleMessage(historyMessage.mid, $event)" data-msg-id="-1">
```

And here is my Python code:

```
messageID= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect']//ng-click//data-msg-id")
print(MessageID)
```

The output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the elements first and then get the data attribute value later:

```
elements= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect']")
```

You can loop on the elements or just get the first element:

```
messageID = elements[0].get_attribute('data-msg-id')
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I typed it wrong. Works fine. 
Thank you alot.
How about the loop? Can I just loop it with For?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure! if you have many elements, use: `for e in elements: ... `